# addEventListener only running once. Can someone explain why?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have the following JavaScript code that is only running once.

I think i need to put it in some type of loop but i'm not sure exactly how. I'm extremely new to JavaScript so if there are some major rookie mistakes in the way i structured the code i apologize in advance. It works perfectly the first time.

I can click submit and the inputs are posted to the page and the edit button appears. When i click the edit button it displays the input fields again like it should. However when I click submit the second time around after editing the input, everything disappears and the screen goes blank.

```
const button = document.getElementById('submitArticleButton');
const editButton = document.getElementById('editPost');
const p = document.getElementById('userArticleContent');
const h1 = document.getElementById('userArticleHeader');
const inputFields = document.querySelector('.inputFields');
const newArticleDiv = document.querySelector('#newArticle');


button.addEventListener('click', () => {


    const inputHeader = document.getElementById('headline').value;
    const inputContent = document.getElementById('articleContent').value;
    inputFields.style.display = 'none';
    p.innerHTML = inputContent;
    h1.innerHTML = inputHeader;
    editButton.style.display = 'block';//previously set to display none with css

});

editButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    inputFields.style.display = 'block';
    newArticleDiv.style.display = 'none';

});
```

HTML
     
    
    Headline or Title

```
<label for="articleContent">Enter your content here</label><br>
<textarea id="articleContent" placeholder="Once upon a time.....">
</textarea>
<button id="submitArticleButton">Submit!</button>

</div>

<div id="newArticle">
<h1 id="userArticleHeader"></h1>
<p id="userArticleContent"></p>
<button id="editPost">Edit</button>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: post your  html .

Comment: It is working fine. Bring your issue in the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/yhndxa9e/8/

Comment: edited to add html @gawicks

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y71p7se4/3/   @SureshPonnukalai your fiddle has too many input field and doesn't function the way i want. Please look at my fiddle and see if you know what is wrong.

Comment: @KenThomas given my answer below. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove  the line `newArticleDiv.style.display = 'none';`

```
editButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    inputFields.style.display = 'block';
    //newArticleDiv.style.display = 'none';

});
```

Comment: This keeps the script from ending but it keeps the newArticleDiv present and displaying underneath the input fields once the edit button is clicked. I would prefer to have only the inputFields or the newArticleDiv displaying at one time.  However setting the innerHTML of p and h1 to an empty string when the edit button is clicked has the effect I wanted.  Thank you!

Comment: @KenThomas You could improve the original code in many ways. I simply pointed out only the problem, to not to confuse you. Please up-vote or accept the answer if it answers your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The screen goes blank, because you are not displaying the `newArticle` division for the second time. In the beginning you are hiding the edit button using CSS. So It does not have anything, so you are seeing only two textboxes with the submit button. Once you click the submit button, you are hiding the `inputFields` and adding information into `p` and `h1` tags and enabling `edit` button.

Now if you click the edit button, you are hiding the `newArticle` div which has the `p`, `h` and `edit` button, and displaying the two textbox with the submit button div. Now if you click again the submit, you have to display the `newArticle` div, otherwise you can't see anything. Because it was in `display:none` status. So you have to update that code like below.

```
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {      
    const inputHeader = document.getElementById('headline').value;
    const inputContent = document.getElementById('articleContent').value;
    inputFields.style.display = 'none';
    p.innerHTML = inputContent;
    h1.innerHTML = inputHeader;
    newArticleDiv.style.display = 'block'; /* this line should added */
    editButton.style.display = 'block';
 });
```

Here is the Snippet with your updated fiddle and check it out how it is working.

```js
    const button = document.getElementById('submitArticleButton');
 const editButton = document.getElementById('editPost');
 const p = document.getElementById('userArticleContent');
 const h1 = document.getElementById('userArticleHeader');
 const inputFields = document.querySelector('.inputFields');
 const newArticleDiv = document.querySelector('#newArticle');
 
 
 button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const inputHeader = document.getElementById('headline').value;
  const inputContent = document.getElementById('articleContent').value;
  inputFields.style.display = 'none';
  p.innerHTML = inputContent;
  h1.innerHTML = inputHeader;
        newArticleDiv.style.display = 'block';
  editButton.style.display = 'block';
  // create edit button
 });
 
 editButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  inputFields.style.display = 'block';
  newArticleDiv.style.display = 'none';      
 });
```

```css
   
    body {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
 }     
 #headline,
 #articleContent {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin:.5em 0;
 }     
 #articleContent {
  min-height:  20em;      
 }     
 label {      
  font-weight: bold;
 }     
 #editPost {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="inputFields">
<label for="headline">Headline or Title</label><br>
<input type="text" id="headline" placeholder="Enter your title here"><br>

<label for="articleContent">Enter your content here</label><br>
<textarea id="articleContent" placeholder="Once upon a time....."></textarea>
<button id="submitArticleButton">Submit!</button>

</div>

<div id="newArticle">
<h1 id="userArticleHeader"></h1>
<p id="userArticleContent"></p>
<button id="editPost">Edit</button>
</div>
```